# AWS Serverless XML endpoint that consumes and responds in XML

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, serverless

Is it possible to have a AWS Lambda that consumes and produces XML? This is for an external API integration that understands only XML.

- I use the C# .netcore 2.1
- I tried to replace `[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]` with a XML equivalent but could not find one.
- I tried the code without a serializer but that errors out with `Object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' cannot be converted to type 'Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayProxyRequest'.`
- Is there a raw text version of the the API gateway so that I can handle the serialization and deserialization?

I found [this](https://github.com/mwittenbols/How-to-use-Lambda-and-API-Gateway-to-consume-XML-instead-of-JSON) article but it seems to be a very convoluted method for a seemingly simple feature.

Answer (score 1):

As your lambda is behind Api Gateway, you can handle XML (de)serialization on the level of Api Gateway integration mapping templates. You need to define mapping templates for XML request (Content-Type=application/xml) and response (Accept=application/xml).

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-integration-settings.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html for more details.

Comment: Yes, that's what's being explained in the link I added. Was not convinced that's the way forward. Anyways ended up  doing the same :)